# Do free hosted blogs/websites on Joomla.com get adds?

Tags: joomla

I am creating a free-hosted website on Joomla.com. This is similar to free blogs/websites on wordpress.com. However, on wordpress.com, wordpress inserts adds on free blogs. I am wondering if the same happens on Joomla.com?

Comment: No, there aren't any ads: example: http://stackexchange.joomla.com/

Comment: @Lodder Is this stated explicitly somewhere in the documentation, or the privacy policy, or something? Is there a written guarantee they won't put adds?